# How the callback is executed in this function?

Tags: javascript, callback

```js
const getData = (cb) => {  
  setTimeout( () => {
    cb({ data: ['there', 'is', 'stuff', 'here'] })
  }, 100)
}

getData( data => {  
  console.log(data);
});
```

Here is the example of the javascript callback. Could some one let me know how this functions is executed into the javascript callback?

Here what is the function inside `getData(cb)` ? How it will be executed ? How the functions is passed as callback inside `cb` and return to the `console.log`

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function inside `getData` is a callback being passed to `setTimeout`, which is one way to schedule a call to a function to happen in the future. In this case, it's asking for that callback to happen roughly 100ms later. `getData` returns before that happens.

The `setTimeout` callback is a *closure*¹ over the context where it's created, which means it has access to `cb` even after `getData` has returned. So when the browser's timer calls the callback, the callback can call `cb`. The call to `cb` uses an object literal to create an object to pass to `cb`.

In the call to `getData`, the author is passing a function as `cb` that logs the data it receives.

So:

1. `getData` is called, passing in a function that will log the argument it gets.
2. `getData` calls `setTimeout` to schedule a callback in about 100ms, passing in another function for the timer to call.
3. `getData` returns.
4. About 100ms later, the browser's timer subsystem triggers a call to the callback passed to `setTimeout`.
5. That callback creates an object and calls `cb`, passing the object to it.
6. *That* callback (the one passed to `getData`) logs the `data` object it receives.

---

¹ "closure" — see: [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work), [my anemic blog](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html)

Comment: Thanks for the details explaination

Answer (score 1):

In order to understand the code you can just simplify it by naming the anonymous functions. One example could be:

```
function logData(data) {
    console.log(data);
}

const getData = (cb) => {  
    // `cb` is `logData` function when `getData` is called
    function timeoutCallback() {
        var data = { data: ['there', 'is', 'stuff', 'here'] };
        cb(data);
    }
    setTimeout(timeoutCallback, 100)
}

getData(logData);
```

Does that make sense?

Answer (score -1):

1- first global execution context created
2- get data function will be called then it will wait for 10 seconds inside the event loop then it will be come to execution context and printed to console.